# How do I create a "double" line feature from GeoJSON data with React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) to plot a GeoJSON file with several `LineString` features. I can plot and style them using

`<GeoJSON data={lines} style={onEachLineFeatureStyle}/>`

where the `onEachLineFeatureStyle` function returns a style appropriate for the line feature, based on the feature's attributes.

I would now like to style some of these Line String features using a "double line" style, like this:
[image]

I have found [an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/adding-offset-to-geojson-layer-in-leaflet) of how to do this using the the [Leaflet.PolylineOffset](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) plugin but I can't figure out how to do this with react-leaflet specifically.

I'm a competent C and Python programmer but very new to using modern JS and especially to React.